# Matlab function command

Tags: matlab, function, variables

Assume that I have a subfunction seen in the below. What is the difference between these two

```
function a=b(x,y)
.
.
.
a=output
```

and

```
function b(x,y)
......
```

---

if I write it in second form how can I define it main function and how can I see its outputs.

---

Another question,

I found a code from  here (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21443-multiple-rapidly-exploring-random-tree--rrt-)  including a function like:

```
%% SetObstacleFilename
    function SetObstacleFilename(self,value)
        if isa(value,'char')
            self.obstacleFilename = value;
            self.GenerateObstacles();
        end
    end
```

how can I use it in my main function? Moreover what is self.GenerateObstacles() command? There is no equality on it?

Comment: I think you should post 2 different questions. Moreover can you format the code for your 1st question so that its more readable please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see how both of your questions are related to the same thing. You really should've asked something along the lines of:

> I always saw MATLAB functions written in the form `function a=b(x,y)`, however recently I came across [some code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21443-multiple-rapidly-exploring-random-tree--rrt-) which included functions in the form `function b(x,y)` (e.g. `function SetObstacleFilename(self,value)`).... so what's up with that?

In order to understand the 2nd type of functions, you need to consider *object-oriented programming (OOP)*.

The code example you found is taken from within a MATLAB `class`. Class-related functions are known in OOP as "methods", and this specific code in another programming language would take the shape of a [`void` return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type) function\method.

Now consider the term `object` that refers to an instance of a `class`.

Traditionally, methods are limited to a single output. For this reason, some methods are designed to operate on `objects` (actually `pointers`, AKA "passing by reference") such that returning a value is not necessary at all, because the input objects are directly manipulated. Other cases when methods don't *need* to return anything may include functions that have some "utility" functionality (e.g. initialize something, plot something, output something to the console etc. - just like the `self.GenerateObstacles()` method you mentioned).

Regarding your other questions:

- The `self` in `SetObstacleFilename(self,value)` looks like an instance of the considered class.
- Usually to use class methods you need to instantiate an object using a constructor (which should be a function with the **same name** of the class), unless these methods are `static`.

To conclude - above are just the most fundamental basics of OOP. I won't attempt to teach you the whole OOP Torah while standing on one leg, so I am providing some additional materials below, should you be interested to further your understanding of the topic.

Hopefully, what's going on is a bit clearer now!

---

Here are some resources for you:

1. [MATLAB's OOP Manual](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matlab_oop.pdf).
2. [MATLAB's documentation on OOP](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/object-oriented-programming.html).